# How to show image form another folder in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to show picture form another folder. But why it's not working?

```
<img src="/picture/Capture.JPG" style="width:600px;height:400px">
```

My folder name is picture and image name is Capture.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print images ,css and js files correct path laravel have a default function `asset()`

Try this
`<img src="{{ asset('picture/Capture.jpg') }}" style="height:400px;width:400px" >`

Answer (score -1):

I find my solution last night.
At first i create a folder in public folder name images. Then i store the picture. And the code formet is here.

```
<img src="{{url('/images/6.JPG')}}" alt="Image"/>
```